# Postman: Unset cookie function is not working

Tags: cookies, postman, newman

I am running my collection and in one case I want to clear the cookie(clear login session) programmatically. I followed the documentation provided by postman (https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/cookies/) but that does not seem to be working. Is there any way to delete the cookies programmatically in my postman.

I am using the following code in the "Tests" tab of postman

```
const cookieJar = pm.cookies.jar();
cookieJar.unset(url, "cookiename", function (error) {
});
```

When I hit send it shows "There was an error in evaluating the test script:  TypeError: cookieJar.unset is not a function" in the console and when I go to cookies in postman the cookie is not getting deleted

Answer (score 2):

Beginning in Postman 7.3.5, you have to Whitelist the domain of the cookie. I was then able to manipulate cookies in a pre-request script to delete the cookie. Not sure whether it will work in the test script.

Here are the [instructions](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3312#issuecomment-516965288).

Comment: What about Newman? Will Newman be able to programmatically set/unset cookies without some kind of whitelisting?  I checked the CLI guide and there was nothing about cookies.

Comment: According to this github comment [1], Newman does not need whitelisting.

[1]: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3312#issuecomment-537408152